# First selenium program not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I've just loaded `Python` `Selenium` into my `Ubuntu` system and I'm following the Getting Started tutorial on [ReadTheDocs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage).  When I run this program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Scraper/test-selenium.py", line 4, in <module> driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__self.binary, timeout)    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable % (self.profile.path))  
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp8xr2V3 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using selenium 2.53.6

The issue is compatibility of firefox with selenium, since firefox>= 48 need Gecko Driver(https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) to run testcases on firefox. or you can downgrade the firefox to 46..from this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/

Comment: Spot on with selenium.  Where can I get the Gecko Driver?

Comment: I've decided to install ChromeDriver instead as it is easy but this got me on right track - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a problem with the webdriver - do you have Firefox installed on your RasPi?

(If not, this might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=150438)

Comment: I'm not on a RasPi and I do have Firefox installed.  Version 49